# How can I fix this regex to allow a specific string?

Tags: regex, sanitization

This regex comes from Atwood and is used to filter out anchor tags with anything other than the href and a title:

```
 <a\shref="(\#\d+|(https?|ftp)://[-A-Za-z0-9+&@#/%?=~_|!:,.;]+)"(\stitle="[^"]+")?\s?>
```

I need to allow am additional attribute that specifically matches: target="_blank".  So the following url should be allowed:

```
 <a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">
```

I tried changing the pattern to these:

```
 <a\shref="(\#\d+|(https?|ftp)://[-A-Za-z0-9+&@#/%?=~_|!:,.;]+)"(\stitle="[^"]+")(\starget="_blank")?\s?>
 <a\shref="(\#\d+|(https?|ftp)://[-A-Za-z0-9+&@#/%?=~_|!:,.;]+)"(\stitle="[^"]+")(\starget=\"_blank\")?\s?>
```

Clearly I don't know regex very well.  How should the pattern be adjusted to allow the blank target and no other targets?

Comment: You shouldn't use regex to parse HTML: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: Why thats certainly an interesting answer it seems a little silly to take it literally and in all cases.  What I am using it for is a simple sanitization routine meant only to ensure a few basic tags are allowed.  Regex certainly seems up to this task even if *I* am not. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<a\shref="(\#\d+|(https?|ftp)://[-A-Za-z0-9+&@#/%?=~_|!:,.;]+)"\s(target=\"_blank\")>
```

Will do what you are asking.

If you are a regex nub, let me recommend RegExBuddy.  It is a program that lets you test your regex's on sample text or sample files.

Saves a lot of time.

http://www.regular-expressions.info/regexbuddy.html (Regex Buddy)

http://www.regular-expressions.info is also a good resource

Comment: Note that this solution imposes that the said attributes (href, target and title) have a specific order.

Comment: I was using this url to test with but hadn't come up with a pattern that worked. http://derekslager.com/blog/posts/2007/09/a-better-dotnet-regular-expression-tester.ashx

Answer (score 1):

```
<a\shref="(\#\d+|(https?|ftp)://[-A-Za-z0-9+&@#/%?=~_|!:,.;]+)"(\stitle="[^"]+")(\starget="_blank")>
```